# Add Search Form to Dropdown menu

Tags: search, dropdown

I am wondering if its possible to have a search form within a dropdown menu. I can add it to the main menu (base) but not quite sure how to actually go about adding it to a sub-menu of one of the main menu items.

Has anyone encountered this issue before and is there a fix I can use ? Hopefully something linked to Wordpress it self (even a plugin if one exists).

Comment: Yes, you can, but you should add the code for context.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ended up just getting the form through PHP and injecting it to the required position using Jquery. :)